# Modify the message body from spring-cloud-stream app starter

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am new to Spring Cloud Stream. My use case is to read from a file source and publish messages (to Kafka) for each line in the file. I have tried using the file source app starter (https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/file/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-file) and have been able to publish messages.

However the I now need to tweak the body of the message before publishing. The app starter generates generic messages and I need to modify the structure before publishing. I have tried searching on SO but haven't found any suitable example. Can anyone please suggest on how to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is a new feature that we're going to blog soon, but I'll try to explain it here. I believe you want to extend the existing app, so in this case you simply want to create a new app that extends *source-file* and then use newly added Spring Cloud Function support to simply compose your transformer into the existing app.
First, you need to make sure you're using the newest Spring Cloud Stream which should be Fishtown.RC1 (2.1.0.RC1).
Also, we have an [example (which is going to be used for the blog)](https://github.com/ilayaperumalg/sandbox/tree/master/function-composition/http-transformer) that you may find useful. It actually does exactly what you're looking for; Only instead of extending `file-source` it extends `http-source` which means you simply have to swap a dependency in the pom from `spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-http` to `spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-file` and then simply define a Bean of type Function where you define your transformation and provide a property during teh startup `--spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=uppercase` where `uppercase` is the name of the function you want to compose at the tail of file source.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyAppExtender {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyAppExtender.class, "--spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=uppercase");
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
        return x -> x.toUpperCase();
    } 
}
```

Anyway, I know the above explanation may be missing a few parts, but give it a shot and see if you have a follow up questions. I'll make sure I'll post the blog when it's ready.

Comment: Many thanks, I have tried as you suggested and was able to successfully achieve this.

Comment: I am glad it helped and watch for https://spring.io/blog, the more details blog will be coming shortly

Answer (score 0):

Messages are immutable.

Add a `.transform()` method to the `flowBuilder()`.

See [transformers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-transformers).

Comment: Can you please explain a little on this? I have just imported the `FileSourceConfiguration.class` in my app and passed the required properties to use the starter.  
The `flowBuilder` is within the `FileSourceConfiguration` class - in that case how do I add a `.transform()`? Should I just re-write the `fileSourceFlow()` from the `FileSourceConfiguration` in my app and add the `.transform()` there?

Comment: Yes, I mean you will need a custom flow; start with the one in `FileSourceConfiguration` and modify it as needed.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I was able to do this, but in the end I went ahead and implemented the Function approach as mentioned by Oleg  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53336105/modify-the-message-body-from-spring-cloud-stream-app-starter/53349369#53349369]