# Using AggregateApplicationBuilder with a HTTP Source binding

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

My goal is to create a synchronous process that can be called by a REST endpoint. In my real world need, this will handle user edits from a web interface while an asynchronous pipeline consisting of the same processes set up as separate services handles data being sent via an event stream. We want the HTTP call to be synchronous so that results can be shown as soon as the edits have been run through the process.

For the purpose of my example below, I have a source, a process and a sink. I want to use Spring Cloud Stream's AggregateApplicationBuilder to create an aggregate of the processes using a RestController as the Source, but my example below simply creates the application and the starts shutting it down as soon as it has been completely wired up.

Is it possible to use AggregateApplicationBuilder this way? I haven't been able to figure out how to get the resulting AggregateApplication to run as a web application.

Application class:

```
package com.example.aggregate;

import com.example.aggregate.controller.FooController;
import com.example.aggregate.processor.BarProcess;
import com.example.aggregate.sink.SinkService;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.aggregate.AggregateApplicationBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AggregateApplicationBuilder()
            .web(true)
            .from(FooController.class)
            .via(BarProcess.class)
            .to(SinkService.class)
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

The controller as Source:

```
package com.example.aggregate.controller;

import com.example.aggregate.dto.Foo;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.HashMap;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/foo")
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class FooController {

    private Source source;

    public FooController(Source source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void handleRequest(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
        foo.putValue("Received", Instant.now().toString());
        sendMessage(foo);
    }

    private void sendMessage(Foo foo) {
        Message<Foo> message = MessageBuilder.createMessage(foo, new MessageHeaders(new HashMap<>()));
        source.output().send(message);
    }
}
```

The processor:

```
package com.example.aggregate.processor;

import com.example.aggregate.dto.Foo;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;

@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class BarProcess {
    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
    public Message<Foo> doFoo(Message<Foo> message) {
        Foo foo = message.getPayload();
        foo.putValue("BarProcess", "completed");
        return MessageBuilder.createMessage(foo, message.getHeaders());
    }
}
```

The sink class (for now, I'm just trying to log the results to System.out):

```
package com.example.aggregate.sink;

import com.example.aggregate.dto.Foo;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Sink;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class SinkService {

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void processPayload(Message<Foo> payload) {
        System.out.println("*****SINK*****");
        System.out.println("Received: " + payload);
    }
}
```

And finally, the simple Foo class:

```
package com.example.aggregate.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Foo {

    private Map<String, String> values;

    public void putValue(String key, String value) {
        if (values == null)
            values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put(key, value);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}
```

The output when I run the Spring application is:

```
2018-12-18 18:12:00.104  INFO 94095 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1bd4fdd: startup date [Tue Dec 18 18:12:00 PST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-12-18 18:12:00.301  INFO 94095 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4218ca6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.2.RELEASE)

2018-12-18 18:12:00.398  INFO 94095 --- [           main] c.e.aggregate.SyncPipelineApplication    : The following profiles are active: local
2018-12-18 18:12:00.408  INFO 94095 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6a57ae10: startup date [Tue Dec 18 18:12:00 PST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1bd4fdd
2018-12-18 18:12:00.475  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.i.config.IntegrationRegistrar        : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2018-12-18 18:12:00.519  INFO 94095 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2018-12-18 18:12:00.521  INFO 94095 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2018-12-18 18:12:00.705  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
2018-12-18 18:12:00.864  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
2018-12-18 18:12:00.864  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2018-12-18 18:12:00.864  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2018-12-18 18:12:00.864  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application-1.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2018-12-18 18:12:00.864  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2018-12-18 18:12:00.865  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147482647
2018-12-18 18:12:00.869  INFO 94095 --- [           main] c.e.aggregate.SyncPipelineApplication    : Started SyncPipelineApplication in 1.089 seconds (JVM running for 1.438)
2018-12-18 18:12:00.891  INFO 94095 --- [           main] com.example.aggregate.sink.SinkService   : The following profiles are active: local
2018-12-18 18:12:00.893  INFO 94095 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@54227100: startup date [Tue Dec 18 18:12:00 PST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6a57ae10
2018-12-18 18:12:01.024  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application-1-1.input' has 1 subscriber(s).
2018-12-18 18:12:01.024  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
2018-12-18 18:12:01.024  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147482647
2018-12-18 18:12:01.027  INFO 94095 --- [           main] com.example.aggregate.sink.SinkService   : Started SinkService in 0.153 seconds (JVM running for 1.596)
2018-12-18 18:12:01.044  INFO 94095 --- [           main] c.e.aggregate.processor.BarProcess       : The following profiles are active: local
2018-12-18 18:12:01.046  INFO 94095 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@35fe2125: startup date [Tue Dec 18 18:12:01 PST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6a57ae10
2018-12-18 18:12:01.143  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application-1-2.input' has 1 subscriber(s).
2018-12-18 18:12:01.144  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
2018-12-18 18:12:01.144  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147482647
2018-12-18 18:12:01.145  INFO 94095 --- [           main] c.e.aggregate.processor.BarProcess       : Started BarProcess in 0.116 seconds (JVM running for 1.714)
2018-12-18 18:12:01.158  INFO 94095 --- [           main] c.e.aggregate.controller.FooController   : The following profiles are active: local
2018-12-18 18:12:01.162  INFO 94095 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@48c40605: startup date [Tue Dec 18 18:12:01 PST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6a57ae10
2018-12-18 18:12:01.244  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
2018-12-18 18:12:01.244  INFO 94095 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147482647
2018-12-18 18:12:01.246  INFO 94095 --- [           main] c.e.aggregate.controller.FooController   : Started FooController in 0.1 seconds (JVM running for 1.815)
2018-12-18 18:12:01.247  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6a57ae10: startup date [Tue Dec 18 18:12:00 PST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1bd4fdd
2018-12-18 18:12:01.248  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@54227100: startup date [Tue Dec 18 18:12:00 PST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6a57ae10
2018-12-18 18:12:01.248  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147482647
2018-12-18 18:12:01.249  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase -2147482648
2018-12-18 18:12:01.249  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@35fe2125: startup date [Tue Dec 18 18:12:01 PST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6a57ae10
2018-12-18 18:12:01.250  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147482647
2018-12-18 18:12:01.250  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase -2147482648
2018-12-18 18:12:01.250  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@48c40605: startup date [Tue Dec 18 18:12:01 PST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6a57ae10
2018-12-18 18:12:01.250  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147482647
2018-12-18 18:12:01.250  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase -2147482648
2018-12-18 18:12:01.251  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147482647
2018-12-18 18:12:01.251  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2018-12-18 18:12:01.251  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2018-12-18 18:12:01.251  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application-1.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2018-12-18 18:12:01.251  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2018-12-18 18:12:01.251  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase -2147482648
2018-12-18 18:12:01.252  INFO 94095 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any guidance on how to keep the application running? When I replace the controller source with one that uses an InboundChannelAdapter, it works the way I expect it to, with messages being sent according to the poller timing.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David, while we haven't really made any formal announcement yet, the AggregatorBuilder is effectively deprecated ;) We don't talk about it any more and you may noticed that latest snapshot documentation no longer has a section for it.

This means we have a much better and simpler way to address your need and that is with Function composition. We are currently working on the blog to publish it prior to the 2.1.0.RELEASE of Spring Cloud Stream which will happen at the beginning of January (we are in RC4 now), so first and foremost you need to switch to use the latest versions.

Now, the support is thru addition of Spring Cloud Function programming model to Spring Cloud Stream. You can read more about it [here](https://spring.io/blog/2018/10/30/spring-cloud-stream-fishtown-rc1-2-1-0-rc1-release-announcement).
Also, a similar question was asked a while back on this forum so [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53336105/modify-the-message-body-from-spring-cloud-stream-app-starter/53349369#53349369) should provide you with the answer you're looking for. In fact it references a sample application on GitHub that uses Http source, essentially demonstrating an identical case.

Please go through it and let us know if you still have any issues.

Cheers,
Oleg